# Best way to complete asyncio gather if one task is complete

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio

I have the following code where function_1 and function_2 runs independently. However, I want the script to complete once function_2 is complete.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

class class_example():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        asyncio.run(self.main())

    async def main(self):
        f1=asyncio.create_task(self.function_1())
        f2=asyncio.create_task(self.function_2())
        a = await asyncio.gather(f1, f2)
        
    async def function_1(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        while True:
            print(f'{(datetime.now().strftime("%F - %H:%M:%S:%f"))} - function_1')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def function_2(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            print(f'{(datetime.now().strftime("%F - %H:%M:%S:%f"))} - function_2')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if i == 10:
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.close()
                break

class manuel_run():
    def __init__(self):
        class_example(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = manuel_run()
```

I get this error message:
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

I added a try/except for the error message and it works...but I believe there should be a better way to do this?

```
        try:
            a = await asyncio.gather(f1, f2)
        except RuntimeError as error:
            print(error)
            if 'Cannot close a running event loop' in str(error):
                print("FINISHED")
            else:
                print(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unconditionally closing the event loop seems like a bad idea in the general case, since you may well have finalisation tasks that need to run before the program ends.

The easy and proper way out would be to `cancel` the other task. You can either do that by providing `function_2` access to `f1` by making it an attribute on your instance; or (better) using [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) (or maybe `as_completed` or other) in `main`:

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([f1, f2], return_when=asyncio. FIRST_COMPLETED)
a = await (list(done)[0])
list(pending)[0].cancel()
```

Note that you still might want to await the cancelled task.

Comment: Thanks, I put the piece of code in the main and remove the loops in the f2. I am getting     a = await done[0]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: OK, I guess it's a set and not a list.

Comment: Yeah, it is a set, so still can't make it work :(. Any idea on how to work with set in this context?

Comment: I already edited